# Numbering of linguex \ag. starts erroneously with a dot

Tags: numbering, linguex

I try to number my examples with numbers and letters. Unfortunately the numbering starts only from the second point with a.) but the first example is only a dot. After some experiments with taking out other packages, I nailed  down the tipa package that seems to cause the trouble. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tipa} % <- TIPA seems to cause the troubles
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

% ... Many other examples here

\ex. \ag. Ambe-in. \\
          swim-1SG.IPFV\\
          ''I swam.''
     \bg. Amben-an-an. \\
          swim-IRR-1SG.PFV \\
          ''I will swim.''
     \cg. Ambe-od-in.\\
          swim-DUR-1SG.IPFV\\
          ''I am swimming.''
     \dg. Amben-a.\\
          swim-1SG.IMP\\
          ''Let me swim!''

\end{document}
```

This is what I get:
[image]

What can I do to start the numbering with a.) ?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: I can't reproduce the output. Your code runs fine for me.

Comment: Please, make an example that shows the behavior, because the output from the given code is as expected. There is possibly some conflict of packages or a redefinition of important commands.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error in another document by adding all the packages I actually use. (I've updated the code above with all the packages). By taking out one after another it seems that the tipa package is causing the trouble. I guess that \a. is also defined in tipa. Has anyone a clue about what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `linguex` package redefines `\a`, `\b`, `\c` and `\d`. The first does not cause real problems, the other three instead do, because they are important commands in LaTeX and should ***never*** be redefined. The package tries to be smart, but if used in combination with `tipa` the smartness fails.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\NewCommandCopy{\linguexb}{\b}
\NewCommandCopy{\linguexc}{\c}
\NewCommandCopy{\linguexd}{\d}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\apptocmd{\Exformat}{%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\b}{\linguexb}%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\c}{\linguexc}%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\d}{\linguexd}%
}{}{}

\begin{document}

% ... Many other examples here
\ex. \ag. Ambe-in. \\
          swim-1SG.IPFV\\
          ''I swam.''
     \bg. Amben-an-an. \\
          swim-IRR-1SG.PFV \\
          ''I will swim.''
     \cg. Ambe-od-in.\\
          swim-DUR-1SG.IPFV\\
          ''I am swimming.''
     \dg. Amben-a.\\
          swim-1SG.IMP\\
          ''Let me swim!''

\end{document}
```

This way, the commands `\b`, `\c` and `\d` get the meaning expected by `linguex` only inside the argument to `\ex`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `\ag` command in `linguex` calls `\a`, which in turn calls `\b`. In `tipa` the command `\b` is redefined.

A solution is to store the original `\b` from `linguex` in another macro with a different name (for example `\lgxb`), and then patch the `\a` command to use the new macro instead of `\b`. Obviously you need to store the original definition *before* you load `tipa`, otherwise the command is already redefined.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{linguex}
\let\lgxb\b
\patchcmd{\a}{\b}{\lgxb}{\typeout{patch ok}}{\typeout{patch failed}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tipa} % <- TIPA seems to cause the troubles
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
% ... Many other examples here
\ex. \ag. Ambe-in. \\
          swim-1SG.IPFV\\
          ''I swam.''
     \bg. Amben-an-an. \\
          swim-IRR-1SG.PFV \\
          ''I will swim.''
     \cg. Ambe-od-in.\\
          swim-DUR-1SG.IPFV\\
          ''I am swimming.''
     \dg. Amben-a.\\
          swim-1SG.IMP\\
          ''Let me swim!''

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]